# Why the same nsm file(Naming Stardard file) can translate words to Abbrivations in one erwin file, but it doesn't work for another erwin file?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, erwin

the nsm file is like this
[image]

and it successfully translated for one erwin. See below picture.
[image]

but I don't know why the same nsm file doesn't work for another of my erwin file? I don't know what the difference with these two erwin file. Maybe some setting is different? I am using CA erwin 7.3.

Any ideas? How can I translate the attributes into columns in PDM for my another erwin file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem is I should check the three checkbox...

[image]